# How to change the manufacturer property in the Android emulator?

Tags: android, emulation

I am running the Android emulator that comes with the Android Studio software. I created an AVD based on Pixel 2. Opening the ADB shell I get:

```
$ getprop ro.product.manufacturer
unknown
```

I would like to change the string returned as property `ro.product.manufacturer`, because I have an app the refuses to run on an "unknown" device. How can I do that?

The file `config.ini` for the AVD has a line

```
hw.device.manufacturer=Google
```

but this does not seem to be the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

despite the old question, I will answer it, as it may be useful for someone when searching.

have you tried using:

```
$adb shell su root setprop
```

???